# Room- LiveData RxJava triggered without reason

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have an Activity, ViewModel, Singleton repository and Room.
In activitiy's `OnCreate` I create the ViewModel:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
viewModel.myData.observe(this, Observer { data ->
        Log.d("livedata","triggred")
   })
```

MainViewModel:

```
class MyWorkoutViewModel (application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    // Getting the singleton repository
    private var repository = (application as MyApp).repository

    val myData: LiveData<Int> by lazy {
        repository.getData()
    }
}
```

Respository has this function:

```
fun getData(): LiveData<Int> {
    return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(database.myDao()
            .observeData())
}
```

MyDao:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table")
fun fetchData(): Flowable<Int>
```

I have a very strange behavior:
First time when the activity is created the data is fetched fine and everything works. After that I launch second activity while MainActivity remains paused. After returning to the main activity, for no visible reason the LiveData is triggered again.

I tried to switch `LiveDataReactiveStream` to just `database.myDao().observeData()` and returning `LiveData` in Dao instead of `Flowable` and it fixed the strange behavior of that extra trigger when activity is resumed.

However I need the use or rxjava for more complicated actions and threading. Any idea why is that trigger happens?

Comment: When do you start observing the `LiveData`? This is probably related to when and in which lifecycle method you call `liveData.observe(...)`

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I start observing in the "OnCreate" method of the activity

Answer (score 1):

This is how `PublisherLiveData` from `reactivestreams` works. It unsubscribes from publisher in `onInactive()` method and re-subscribes in `onActive()`.

So, when you return to your main activity, `onActive()` triggers, `PublisherLiveData` re-subscribes to Flowable, returned by your repository, and you receive data from repository.

I ended up subscribing to `Flowable` and clearing it manually in `onCleared()` method of `ViewModel` and don't using `reactivestreams`.